# How to write a sql query to inner join 2 tables without duplicate data?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a sql query to select 2 tables without duplicate data?

```
original table 1
--------------
id | salary

01 | 500

01 | 300

02 | 700

02 | 900

original table 2
--------------
id | deduction amount

01 | 50

02 | 20
```

### Code

```
Select t1.salary,t2,deduction amount 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
```

but after applied the command table output get duplicate data, i also try to use group by but not correct

```
id | salary | deduction amount

01 | 500    | 50

01 | 300    | 50

02 | 700    | 20

02 | 900    | 20
```

### Correct output should be

```
id | salary | deduction amount

01 | 500    | 50

01 | 300    | null

02 | 700    | 20

02 | 900    | null
```

Comment: What makes salaries `300` and `900` to be mapped to `null`?

Comment: mysql or sql server or oracle ?  which dbms ?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in the results. It looks like you want to show t2.amount only for some arbitrary row (perhaps the first?) in the subset defined by id. To do that you probably have to use functions that aren't supported on all databases.

Comment: suppose deduction amount should displays one time because id(01) only got one deduction amount, but now show twice

Comment: You have no primary key. This is the root of your problem

Comment: I think the primary key is id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join the two tables, you will get this result and I don't see an easy way to prevent this. This is just how SQL joins work.

One possible solution could be to do a union and give `NULL` or `0` as the salary amount in the deduction rows

```
select id, salary, null as deduction 
from table1 t1 
union
select id, null, `deduction amount`
from table2 t2
```

This will give you something like

```
id | salary | deduction

01 | 500    | null
01 | 300    | null
02 | 700    | null
02 | 900    | null
01 | null   | 50
02 | null   | 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I need join them to produce the table.